# Encrypt Documents In MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, encryption

My use case is I do not want the admin to see the documents in clear text.

I tried to use mongoose encryption, but it does not work. The fields do not get encrypted. Plus, I have existing clear text documents, so auto converting them would be handy instead of starting over.

Any suggestions what plugin or lib you use?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js
Encrypt when writing to DB than. I dont think you much options.

Comment: Exactly for this situation you have the [Client-Side Field Level Encryption](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-client-side-encryption/) Note, it is not available in MongoDB Community Edition.

Comment: oh i see. sad it's not part of community edition. thank you both for the tips.